# UIViews overlap even when setting origin and size to keep them separate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to design a Hamburger Menu, meaning a small button on the top left of the navigation corner, which when pressed, reveals a menu on the left, and leaves the original view partially visible on the right.

However, in my code I have not been able to position the two views (the hamburger menu view, and the main view correctly), and they overlap. Here is what I am doing in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
CGRect frame = self.containerView.bounds;

int widthForHamburgerVC = 150;
CGRect hamburgerVCFrame = frame;
hamburgerVCFrame.size.width = widthForHamburgerVC;
hamburgerVCFrame.origin.x = 0;
self.hamburgerVC.view.frame = hamburgerVCFrame;
self.hamburgerVC.view.bounds = hamburgerVCFrame;

CGRect mainVCFrame = self.containerView.bounds;
mainVCFrame.origin.x = widthForHamburgerVC;
self.mainVC.view.frame = mainVCFrame;

[self.containerView addSubview:self.mainVC.view];
[self.containerView addSubview:self.hamburgerVC.view];
```

`containerView` is the view which consumes the entire screen. So from the code, the intention is to have the hamburgerVC view start from x = 0, and be 150 units wide, and the mainVC view to start from x = 150 and be of the usual width. There shouldn't be any overlap, but it looks like this.

[image: The red is the hamburger view, and it is occluding part of the main view]

The red hamburger view overlaps with the main view. There is about a 50 unit overlap between the two views, which I am not able to account for. I tried to put a breakpoint and check the widths and x coordinates for the two views, and it was as expected (Hamburger View: x = 0, width = 150. Main View: x = 150, width = 320).

Does anyone see any problems with the code to setup these views? Both have autolayouts enabled.

Comment: Try doing it in viewWillAppear. You should never do any laying out of subviews in viewDidLoad, since the frames have not (always) been set yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auto layout, then you should avoid specifying frames. You should adjust the views by changing the constraints. You can make outlets for your constraints in code and specify the change and then call layoutIfNeeded method on the views whose constraints are updated.